# react firebase firestore Expected type 'Pa', but it was: a custom Va object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to receive the data from an uploaded file from firebase firestore and save it in an array

but its throws me an "Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'Pa', but it was: a custom Va object"

Thanks for help

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { projectFirestore } from "../firebase/config";
import { collection as col, onSnapshot, query, orderBy } from "firebase/firestore";


const useFirestore = (collection) => {

    const [docs, setDocs] = useState([]);

    useEffect (() => {
        //new collection reference
        const newcoll = (col(projectFirestore, collection))
            const q = query(newcoll, orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'));
            const unsub = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
                let documents = [];
                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    documents.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
                })
                setDocs(documents);
            });

        return () => newcoll();
    },[collection]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a few changes in the code to be:

```
 useEffect (() => {
   if(collection) { 
     const newcoll = col(projectFirestore, collection);
     const q = query(newcoll, orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'));
     const unsub = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
       let documents = [];
       snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          documents.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
       })
       setDocs(documents);
     });

     return unsub;
  }
},[collection]);
```

Changes include:

- returning `unsub` instead of `() => newcoll()`
- checking that `collection` has a truthy value

Comment: Work thanks , the problem actually was come from another component.

Comment: what was the actual problem? I'm había similar issue